# DateTime.TryParseExact adds one minute?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this conversion:

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/02/2013", "mm/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

The following Assert fails:

```
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013, 1, 2), dateTime);
```

Because TryParseExact adds one hour to the datetime:

```
Expected: 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
But was:  2013-01-02 00:01:00.000
```

Is this related to daylight savings time, and if so, does that mean I shouldn't be using DateTimeStyles.None?

Comment: What is the value of `matchValue`, also TryParseExact expects a format like `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: By passing `null` you actually say: use the current culture's datetime format. Maybe you want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: mm is minutes in format you need to use MM.

Comment: Never mind, @Reniuz spotted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your format `"mm/dd/yyyy"` means **minutes**/days/years. You want `"MM/dd/yyyy"` (uppercase for month). Also, by passing `null` you actually say: use the current culture's datetime format. You probably want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/02/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

This also prevents issues if the current culture does not use `/` as date-separator. Germany, for example, uses `.` as separator, hence the format-string `"MM/dd/yyyy"` would be evaluated as `"MM.dd.yyyy"`. [**Read**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator).

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with your format, lower case `mm` is used for minutes for month it is upper case `MM`. The difference you see between the values is of 1 minutes, not one hour.

Use:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/02/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Comment: In the words of Homer Simpson - DOH!

Comment: I made the same error with "yyyy-mm-dd" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd"