# DateTime.ParseExact returns current date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I tried the following code:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2013",  //string date
                                        "01/02/2013",  // string format
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**I know the format is incorrect.** But why instead of throwing exception it returned the current date `dateTime = {24/09/2014 12:00:00 AM}`.

I know the valid format for my date should be `MM/dd/yyyy`, But Why it didn't throw an exception. I also tried it with `DateTime.TryParseExact`, it returns the current date instead of `default(DateTime)`. This actually came up reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020290/datetime-tryparseexact-adds-one-hour).

My question is how does this parsing work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.100%29):

> If format defines a date with no time element and the parse operation
>   succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a time of midnight
>   (00:00:00). If format defines a time with no date element and the
>   parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of
>   DateTime.Now.Date.

Your format string is the same as value - so parsing goes 'as is' and no exception thrown.
If you will change format string to say, `02/02/2013` - you'll get `FormatException` as expected

Answer (score 5):

There is no day/month placeholders in format string. So it literally matches each character (successfully) and returns default (today) values for each component of the date.

Indeed if there is no exact match it will throw error like (notice mismatch between "11/..." and "01/...")

```
   DateTime.ParseExact("11/02/2013",  
                  "01/02/2013",  // string format
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Behavior is very similar to some reasonable patterns like "MM/yyyy" - expecting month, *than exact match to `/` character*, than year.

Default values are *midnight of current date* [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of DateTime.Now.Date.

Comment: Isn't the default date value is: `{01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}` Do you have any reference where it is picking up current date as default ?

Comment: @user2711965 Again, in the documentation: `If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of DateTime.Now.Date.`

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

> If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of DateTime.Now.Date.